# Chromium doesn't open on my desktop when I run it through ssh but works when opening terminal directly on my desktop

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, chrome, xubuntu

I am running Ubuntu 20.4 and I recently installed Chrome on it.

I wanted to do automation and the fact that neither `headless` nor `xvfb` worked for me, lead me to installing a Xubuntu desktop.

After installing the desktop, I still can connect with ssh but I have noticed some very weird behavior:

- when launching Chrome from a terminal opened in my Ubuntu desktop (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>), it opens normally
- when I launch Chrome from my shell it doesn't work (core dumps)

Expected behavior:

- I want to run `chromium` on my `ssh` connected shell and a `chromium` window to open in my ubuntu desktop.

Can you help?

PS: It is frustrating when so simple things are not working and need background knowledge.

Comment: You must have a very high standard if you call this simple.   This ssh connection is from another system?  When you start Chromium, it may very well try to open a window on the Xubuntu side.  This is determined by the DISPLAY variable.  What is its value?

Comment: Thank you @GerardH.Pille . Setting DISPLAY=:1 solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to verify the value of the DISPLAY variable.  It determines on what X server and screen the window will open.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically get the display variable/location in which the display is open?

Comment: I know the desktop where you are coming from, can be set automatically, but the one on the system you're connecting to, no. You're not connecting to a desktop, with ssh.  Who says there is one?  But, it used to be 0:0 for ages - still is on mine -  I hope it'll be :1 for a long time on standard installs.  So you could add it to your .profile, perhaps?

Comment: Ok!!! Thanks :)